# Measurement procedure and time evolution in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Consider a Hamiltonian $\hat{H}$, with eigenstates $\phi_{i}$ and eigenvalues $E_{i}$. Consider also an operator $\hat{A}$ with eigenstates $f_{i}$ and eigenvalues $a_{i}$ and that every two different eigenstates corresponds to two different eigenvalues, for both operators. The collection is represented by $\Psi$. I am required to compute the probability of measuring $E_{1}$ at $t=0$ and $a_{2}$ after time $t$ of the first measurement, in terms of the above values.

So here are my thoughts: I will not take into consideration the probability of measuring $E_{1}$, because that would be obviously zero. So I will take for granted that I measured $E_{1}$ at $t=0$ and will look for the required probability. Measuring $E_{1}$ at $t=0$ means that $\Psi(x,0)=\phi_{1}$. After time $t$ we will obtain that $\Psi(x,t)=e^{-i\frac{E_{1}}{h}t}\phi_{1}$. So we ask for the transmission probability that of $\Psi(x,t)\rightarrow f_{2}$ or $P_{1}=|(\Psi(x,t),f_{2})|^{2}=|(\phi_{1},f_{2})|^2$. Is this correct ?

Also, if we to calculate the probability that starting from $t=0$ measuring $a_{2}$ and then at time $t$ measuring $E_{1}$, let $P_{2}$, we would obtain $P_{2}=|(f_{2},\phi_{1})|^2=P_{1}$. Is this correct ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It appears good to me.